# ESP-12 + FTDi + platformio

Tags: esp8266, ftdi

I have 2 questions.

1. Why we have to put our functions before void loop and void setup into VScode+platformio?
2. I switched from arduino IDE to VScode+platformio today, when I upload the sketch with platformio into my esp-12, it doesn't work. (It works with arduino IDE)

I have this Warning: `src\main.cpp:46:24: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
 const byte menuColor = 0XF206;`

[EDIT]The problem comes from these lines:

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(enA), enAin, RISING);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(enB), enBin, RISING);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(enBtn), enBtnIn, FALLING);
```

Comment: 1) read [Functions in C++](For question 1, read [Function in C++](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/functions-in-cpp.php) for better understanding on function declaration. For question 2, 0xF206 is 16-bit long, or 2 bytes, so you should declare your variable as use `const unsigned int menuColor = 0xF206;`, and read more [here](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/datatypes-and-modifiers-in-cpp.php).

Comment: "when I upload the sketch"   .... that should say `when I compile the sketch` .... the upload happens after your sketch is successfully compiled .... in your case, the upload to the ESP-12 never happens

Answer (score 1):

> Why we have to put our functions before void loop and void setup into VScode+platformio?

Because that is how C works. The Arduino IDE hides it from you by adding *function prototypes* at the start of your code.

> I switched from arduino IDE to VScode+platformio today, when I upload the sketch with platformio into my esp-12, it doesn't work. (It works with arduino IDE)

```
const byte menuColor = 0XF206;
```

That can never work. The value 0x06 will be assigned to menuColor since a byte is only 8 bits.  You need to learn to use data types that are suitable for the values you are trying to store in them.

Comment: Thank, you I understand my error with menuColor. Now I know what's the problem.


```
#include <Arduino.h>

const int enBtn = 3;

void en(){
    digitalWrite(2,1);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(2,0);
    delay(500);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enBtn, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(enBtn), en, FALLING); //Doesn't work into platformio
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}